# C# Array "circle"

Tags: c#, arrays, counter

I have an array:

```
class Words
{
   public static string[] wordsArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
}
```

TextBlock which displays an array of values, and button that displays the next value of the array:

```
private int counter = 0;

    private void goButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (counter < Words.wordsArray.Length)
        {
            enWordTextBlock.Text = Words.wordsArray[counter++];
        }
    }
```

When the box appears on the last value of the array, the program will continue to not work, how to make it work in a "circle"?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
private void goButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    counter++; //increase the counter
    int i = counter % Words.wordsArray.Length; //modulo operation
    enWordTextBlock.Text = Words.wordsArray[i]; //set text
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: with this code the text after first button click will be "two", unless counter is initialized to -1

Comment: If there are two buttons: NextButton and PreviousButton, when you click NextButton - you will see next value in array; when you click PreviousButton - you will see previous value, but if the first value shows the array, and you click PreviousButton - would be a mistake. How to make if you click PreviousButton if displays last value. "Circle" just the opposite? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
private int counter = 0;

private void goButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    enWordTextBlock.Text = Words.wordsArray[counter++ % Words.wordsArray.Length];
}
```

[Edit]

Ok, this is an edit related to user1397396 comment. I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but you might have a problem with negative value modulus. For example:

```
int counter = 0;
int mod = 4;
counter--; // counter is -1 after this line is executed
int result = counter % mod; // result is -1
result = (counter + mod) % mod; // result is now 3 as desired
```

Here is how I would implement these Next and Previous buttons.

```
private int counter = 0;

private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    enWordTextBlock.Text = Words.wordsArray[counter % Words.wordsArray.Length];
    counter++; // put ++ operator in new line to avoid confusion
}

private void PreviousButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int wordCount = Words.wordsArray.Length;
    // add wordCount before applying modulus (%) to avoid negative results
    // -1 % 5 = -1; -2 % 5 = -2; -6 % 5 = -1 etc
    // negative values would cause exception when accessing array
    counter = ((counter - 1) + wordCount) % wordCount; 
    enWordTextBlock.Text = Words.wordsArray[counter];
}
```

For example, this code would cause pressing Next, Previous, Next to give you this: "one", "four", "one".



Even better solution would be to use a method (or to inline code) such as this:

```
private static int GetPositiveIntModulus(int value, int mod)
{
    return ((value % mod) + mod) % mod;
}
```

It will give you a positive result for any value, even when `value < -mod`. So you could write the code above like this:

```
private int counter = 0;

private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // uncomment this to ensure valid counter
    // if it is changed somewhere else in the program
    //counter = GetPositiveIntModulus(counter, Words.wordsArray.Length);
    enWordTextBlock.Text = Words.wordsArray[counter];
    counter = GetPositiveIntModulus(counter + 1, Words.wordsArray.Length);
}

private void PreviousButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    counter = GetPositiveIntModulus(counter - 1, Words.wordsArray.Length);
    enWordTextBlock.Text = Words.wordsArray[counter];
}
```